# Volatile keyword - is it the only way to protect a value across threads?

Tags: java, volatile

In Java, the `volatile` keyword is for direct read and write from main memory so that reads or writes won't be lost if multiple threads are accessing a variable.

Without using `volatile`, is there any other way to achieve this functionality? I came across this question but couldn't figure out a solution.

Comment: You want to get a variable to act as if it's `volatile` without declaring it as `volatile`? The first question that comes to mind is: why? What problem are you trying to solve? We need more context (and a concrete, practical problem to ground it) if you want more than "you can't do something without doing it."

Comment: You could use the various classes from `java.util.concurrent.atomic`.

Comment: Changing the order of sentences lets them be shorter. Also keywords should be marked up as code.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you want to safely access a non-volatile variable from multiple threads, you need to surround all read/write access to the variable with `synchronized` blocks that use a shared monitor. Read access to `volatile` variables (in general) need not be synchronized, because each read operation is guaranteed to see the last write to the variable by any thread.

It is important to notice that using `volatile` fields alone does not eliminate the need for synchronization when you e.g. need to *atomically* read a value of a variable, followed by a write to the same variable. A common use case for this is incrementing a counter. As @Louis Wasserman suggests, for these purposes, classes in the [`java.util.concurrent.atomic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) package provide reliable and easy to use methods, such as `compareAndSet(...)` and `incrementAndGet()`.

Comment: Just for a little more clarity, read only (immutable) variables don't need to be volatile. Each thread can have their own instance and the value will always be correct. The volatile keywork just makes sure every thread gets the most current value when referenced (if that makes since without showing byte code).

Comment: @IsaiahvanderElst, that's not entirely correct. For example, `String`s are immutable, but if my class has a (non-final) field `private String currentValue` (and a corresponding getter/setter), there is no guarantee that different threads will read the most recent copy of `currentValue`, unless it's declared `volatile`.

Comment: "Using volatile variables, read access ... need not be synchronized."  This is dangerous advice, at best.  The decision to use synchronization will depend on the state transitions that a mutable object can undergo and whether those transitions involve multiple independent fields that must be atomically updated (to avoid reading an object in an invalid state), whether or not those references are declared volatile.

Comment: @scottb, I have re-phrased the sentence. My point was that read access to `volatile` variables need not be synchronized (in general). Do you still disagree?

Comment: @MickMnemonic You're right and what you are saying is what I was trying to verbalize. By immutable I was trying to convey that the value does not change and the reference to the instance does not change. The state cannot change.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Slight nit to your nit :), a `final` field is also thread-safe (as an alternative to `volatile`).

Comment: Can we also try this approach that make the write operation done by one thread to join with other thread that even manipulates the value . Can this approach solves our purpose ?

Comment: @yshavit, yes, if the variable in the `final` field is _immutable_, i.e. read-only. @shubham, I don't think I fully understand what you mean. Could you edit the post if you have follow-up questions?

Answer (score 1):

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) describes a set of *happens-before* relationships, and a set of *synchronizes-with* actions. If one action *synchronizes-with* a following action, it *happens-before*. A write is guaranteed to be visible if *happens-before* a read, in this technical sense.

Writes performed inside a `synchronized` block are visible to threads that synchronize on that lock afterwards, because release of a lock *synchronizes-with* acquisition by another thread.

A write to a `volatile` variable *synchronizes-with* subsequent reads of that variable, so it is visible.

A number of the utilities in the `java.util.concurrent` also provide a *happens-before* relationship. For example, actions taken by a thread before it calls `countDown()` on a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) are visible to threads that return from a call to `await()` on that latch. Of course, many of these APIs achieve this by using `volatile`, `synchronized` themselves.